# Using head tail grep for extracting logs for a unique transaction id

Tags: shell, unix

**Samplelog.log**

```
Log Level A | Start log creation | 123456789
Logging System start
Checking data cache
Sending out email
Stop log creation | 
Log Level A | Start log creation | 987654321
Logging System start
Checking data cache
Sending out email
Stop log creation | 987654321
Log Level A | Start log creation | 121212121
```

**NOTE:** 123456789, 987654321 and 121212121 are transaction IDs

For the above log file, how do I use head, tail and grep that will result in following truncated log:-

```
Log Level A | Start log creation | 987654321
Logging System start
Checking data cache
Sending out email
Stop log creation | 987654321
```

So, basically my requirement is to check the 1st instance of transaction ID - 987654321 and pull the logs until the last instance of this transaction ID. Also, the log files are pretty huge so the approach needs to take care of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v id=987654321 '/ Start log / && $NF==id{p=1}
                     p; /^Stop log / && $NF==id{exit}' sample.log 
Log Level A | Start log creation | 987654321
Logging System start
Checking data cache
Sending out email
Stop log creation | 987654321
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the same. I assume this would have to be executed as a shell script and not command line.

Comment: This is a command line actually. You can just run: `awk -v id=987654321 '/ Start log / && $NF==id{p=1} p; /^Stop log / && $NF==id{exit}' sample.log` from Unix command line.